# Как проверить наличие некоторых символов в строке?

Tags: java, selenium

В строке:

```
{"ID":"53fddc6f-e356-42db-82dc-78e0c3311ece","auth_email":"#fastreg_7f03fc6d092d"}
```

нужно проверить только наличие

```
ID, auth_email, #fastreg
```

Как это можно сделать?

Получается только по отдельности каждое слово, например:

```
String w = (String) js.executeScript("return sp.getResult()");
CharSequence searchStringResult = "ID";
boolean f = w.contains(searchStringResult);
```

Comment: для поиска подстроки в строке используйте регулярные выражения

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF

и ещё
http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Спасибо! У меня были попытки сделать регуляр, но безуспешные:

Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("^ID\\" + "^auth_email\\" + "^#fastreg\\");
Matcher m = p.matcher(w);
boolean h = m.matches();

Answer (score 2):

пример поиска символа а будет чтото вроде

```
bool isContains = ID.toLowerCase().contains("a".toLowerCase())
```